# Unexpected behavior of numpy invert

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering why the following Python code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0], dtype=np.int8)
print(np.invert(a))
```

prints

```
[-1]
```

instead of [0]. According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html), the two's complement of 0 should be returned.

What am I getting wrong?

Ps: numpy version = 1.23.4

Comment: `np.invert` does not return the two's complement: it returns the bit-wise inversion of the array values.

Comment: Documentation is nonsense and contradictory here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher You mean the "For signed integer inputs, the two’s complement is returned." part?

Comment: @9769953 from documentation "For signed integer inputs, the two’s complement is returned". And it is reported a link to Wikipedia page of two's complement.

Comment: @JtTest The first line of the documentation states "Compute bit-wise inversion, or bit-wise NOT, element-wise.". As Michael Butscher points out, the documentation appears to be contradictory.

Comment: @9769953 Exactly. Further down on the page there is stated that `invert` is an alias for `bitwise_not` and there is even a code example that shows that the function does not return the two-complement.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Seems like a documentation bug; someone probably thought bitwise not is the equivalent of two's complement for signed integers, and that slipped through. I can file an issue with NumPy.

Comment: The description of the example says "When using signed integer types the result is the two’s complement of the result for the unsigned type." So not the two's complement of the input but rather the two's complement of the result of `inverse()` for an unsigned int. Which is also not clear because it does not specify the behaviour for negative signed integers as input.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25747 . OP and @MichaelButscher : if you had liked to submit the issue, I can see if the author can be changed (or I'll close this one, and you can copy-paste mine with your own), if you value the authorship/discovery.

Comment: @9769953 thank you for submitting, for me it is ok as it is

Comment: @OskarHofmann This is wrong, too. This would mean the result in signed case would be the bitwise inversion of the bitwise inversion (aka input value itself) plus one. Therefore the result for signed 13 would be 14.

Comment: @9769953 It's ok for me, too.

Comment: I find the text in the example just confusing to read. I've added it to the GitHub issue (lest it be overlooked), and let the NumPy developers decide how to handle this.

Comment: It looks like there'll be a new alias for `invert`, `bitwise_invert`, in NumPy 2.0. Which makes this even clearer (like the `bitwise_not` part). But NumPy 1.x will be around and updated for a long time, and the documentation may be the same for both versions.

Answer (score 1):

`np.invert` does not return the two's complement: it returns the bit-wise inversion of the array values. Thus for 0, it returns 8 bits (since the input is 8 bits) of `11111111`, which for 8-bit signed integers is -1.

Note that the documentation appears to contradict itself. The first sentence states:

> Compute bit-wise inversion, or bit-wise NOT, element-wise.

Two paragraphs down, it states

> For signed integer inputs, the two’s complement is returned.

Given that the first sentence should apply for all values (it doesn't indicate otherwise), this is in contradiction with the second sentence. At least according to the two's complement definition I know of (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). I think this is a a bug in the documentation.

The result you get suggests only the first sentence is correct.

Comment: The numpy documentation of `invert()` literally says: "For signed integer inputs, the two’s complement is returned. " And int8 is signed.

Comment: @OskarHofmann Please see the comments-conversation below the question.